# Terraform - Conditional operator cannot be used with list values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm using Terraform with AWS as a provider.

I want to use a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) in my availability zones local variable.

The logic is simple:

If a variable exist - take it.
If not, use the availability zones `data`.

The following code:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

locals {
  azs  = "${length(var.azs) > 0 ? var.azs :  data.aws_availability_zones.available.names}"
}


variable "azs" {
  description = "A list of Availability zones in the region"
  default     = []
  type        = "list"
}
```

Generates the following error:

> conditional operator cannot be used with list values.

Although its quiet a simple operation, It turns out like a [familiar issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12453).

I followed the work-arounds in the mentioned thread, but they looked looked quiet complicated (Using `compact` `split` and `join` functions together).

Any suggestions for more simple solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are close to the answer.

Not sure how you define the variable `var.azs`, I guess they are defined as string and connected with commas.

So you need adjust the code, [join](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#join-delim-list-) the list to string.

```
locals {
  azs = "${length(var.azs) > 0 ? var.azs :  join(",", data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)}"
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way. Thank you. I'll just mention that I add to do the join also on the var.azs (it is a list) and then, because other places in code expect azs to be list -  I had to save the result in a azs_string local and create a azs local like this: azs = "${list(local.azs_string)}".

Comment: azs = "${list(local.azs_string)}" will still not work @Rtmy .
You will need something like this:
azs = "${split(",", local.azs_string)}"